# Layout Inflater in Android

Tags: android, layout-inflater

There are 3 xml files. `Main.xml` has a linear layout.
`Button.xml` just contains a button.
`txt.xml` just contains an edit text.
I inflate `button.xml` to `Main.xml`.
Looks fine.
Button has the same size as it was in `Button.xml`.
Next i inflate edit text to `Main.xml` which has an ems=10(`android:ems="10"`).
When i run, the button changes its size to same as that of edit text.
How does that happen and how to overcome the problem.  the code is pasted.

Main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".First" />
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    </LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Button.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        />
```

txt.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
     >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Main.java

```
public class First extends Activity {
    LinearLayout lout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        final LayoutInflater inf=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Button btn=(Button)inf.inflate(R.layout.button, null);
        lout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);

        lout.addView(btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(lout.getChildAt(5)==null){
                    EditText e=(EditText)inf.inflate(R.layout.txt, null);
                    lout.addView(e);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

on 5 clicks of the button, 5 edit texts will show up. but the moment i click the button the size of the button changes in addition to the edit text formation.

Comment: Please add your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please paste your code here, only then anybody can help you. Still you can set a layout_height & layout_width of the button to something like 20sp(as per your need).

In your Main.xml file you need to fix the width of the layout as the layout is small at first because the textview is small. But when you click on the Button the layout increases as per the required width for the EditText and so the Button size also increases:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/ll" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_width="100sp" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
</LinearLayout>
```